# Golf some quine stripes in different languages

Tags: code-challenge, quine, source-layout, rosetta-stone

You will choose *m* languages and write *n* programs in each language, each with length *n*m*. The *k*th program should output the *k*th character of each program, ordered by the program number.

For example, in this submission (for demonstration only; they can be any characters including newlines and tabs):

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

Program `ABC` should output `ADG`, and programs `DEF` and `GHI` should output `BEH` and `CFI` respectively.

All programs in the list must not be a normal quine. So `ABC` and `ADG` must be different. Same applies to the other two programs. Note that *n*m* must be at least 2 to make this possible.

You don't have to use your languages in specific order. So you can write two programs in language A, then three in language B, then another in language A again. But all languages must be used exactly the same number of times.

Leading / trailing newline in your program and output doesn't matter.

The answer with minimum *n(m+10)/m<sup>3</sup>* wins. But I'll also award at least +100 bounty to the answer with most languages if it used at least 3 of them. **Deadline for the bounty: after a week without improvement or Mar 1st, 2015 if no answer satisfied the criterion.**

#### Rules about languages

You can use any languages with different names, or different versions which are generally considered different enough (such as Python 2/3, ECMAScript 5/6). But your programs must not output exactly the same thing in any other language you have used.

Answer (score 9):

## CJam, m=1, n=37, score=407

Here is my example answer. It used only one language: CJam.

```
{"_~"+s'A_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'B_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'C_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'D_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'E_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'F_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'G_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'H_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'I_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'J_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'K_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'L_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'M_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'N_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'O_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'P_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'Q_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'R_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'S_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'T_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'U_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'V_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'W_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'X_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'Y_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'Z_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'[_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'\_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s']_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'^_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'__'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'`_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'a_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'b_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'c_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'd_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
{"_~"+s'e_'I={;;'f,'Ai>}{'A-=37*}?}_~
```